# Create Subscription programmatically in Reporting Services

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reporting, subscription

I need to create a **subscription** for my **SSRS** reports in an asp.net page.
I can show the reports in a reportviewer using Reporting.WebForms.
SSRS is on the another computer in my network. For reportviewer, I use "admin" and "pass" for credentials which is the SSRS machine's admin username and password and it's ok. And admin has all the roles for SSRS reports.

But when I try to createSubscription via ReportingService2006 web service I can't make it.
I'm not a professional nor amateur. searched the web a lot.

tried this and the odetocode version of this: 
1. [**technet** - something similar 1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2006.reportingservice2006.createsubscription.aspx)

But couldn't make it happen. Really appriciate any help. thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to setup some of your reports using "Data driven subscriptions". I find its pretty easy to manage this if your going to be doing alot of updates to your report subscriptions. It will allow you to interact with user subscriptions via a custom SQL table.

You can find a MSDN tutorial on setup for Data driven subscriptions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169673.aspx)

Comment: All I need to do, is to create monthly report backups to a folder of all the reports via code. But data driven seems like a dynamic subscriber based thing. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article and source code here, it's the best info on this topic I've found so far.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36009/Programmatically-Playing-With-SSRS-Subscriptions

There is also a class reference here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165967%28v=sql.90%29